# How to start background service on BOOT_COMPLETED event in Android?

Tags: android, notifications, sensors, event-listener, foreground-service

I've developed an application which start a foreground service and that service is implemented **SensorEventListener**. If **onSensorChanged** or **onAccuracyChanged** called it broadcast an intent. This forground service is started on **BOOT_COMPLETED** event and it should not be killed until user stops it.

Now customer requests that foreground service notification should not be displayed. I tried to make it as a background service. but Android system does not allow to start background service on BOOT_COMPLETED event.

What is the best way to start background service on BOOT_COMPLTED event and register for **SensorEventListener**. This Service should be run always until user stop it.

```
minSdkVersion 26
targetSdkVersion 30
```

Thank you